# Notepad++ plugin for multiline Search & Replace

Tags: windows, gratis, notepad++

Notepad++ is great in replacing text, it even allows multiline replacements with the extended rules (`\r\n` etc.).

However, the dialog neither displays search texts in multiple lines nor is the textbox long enough to distinguish long items. A picture may say more than thousand words:

[image: Notepad++ with lines too long]

<strike>Unfortunately, the dialog can also not be resized to make the input box larger.</strike> Meanwhile, the dialog can be resized.

So I am looking for

- a Notepad++ plugin
- for Windows
- which is gratis
- that has longer input fields
- has multiline input fields and can search with simple line breaks (`\r\n` aka. true <kbd>Enter</kbd>) instead of escaped line breaks (`\\r\\n` aka. <kbd></kbd>, <kbd>r</kbd>, </kbd>, n</kbd>)

Was that clear enough?